# PHP regular expression format text

Tags: php, regex

I need help with php5 regex function. I need function which takes arguments text, Regex, string before, after.

```
function Highlight($text, $regex, $before, $after)
```

example is probably the best explanation of what I need.

```
$text="I have apple and banana."
$regex="(apple|banana)"
$before="<b>"
$after="</b>"
```

and I need return

```
"I have <b>apple</b> and <b>banana<b>."
```

an example is only to illustrate the problem and it will not be an html elements.

thank you

Comment: Have you tried [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)?

Comment: Please also include any code that you have tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: Are those strings guaranteed not to be in a HTML-attribute in your text-to-highlight? If so: a simple preg_replace should do it. If however you cannot know for certain, going for a DOM parser & inspect the text nodes individually is less prone to errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
function Highlight($text, $regex, $before, $after) {
    $pattern = '/'. $regex .'/';
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, 
        function ($m) use ($before,$after) {
            return $before.$m[0].$after;
        }
    , $text);
}
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/116065)

Comment: @ComFreek: Absolutely right. I hadn't tested the code before posting the answer. But these errors have been fixed. Thanks for catching that for me!

Answer (score 3):

```
$text="I have apple and banana.";
$regex="(apple|banana)";
$before="<b>";
$after="</b>";

print preg_replace("@".$regex."@", $before."$1".$after, $text);
```